# How do I enable Windows' scp for use from Python?

Tags: python, windows, scp

I can execute `scp.exe` from the command line, but not from Python:

```
(dev) go|c:\> scp
usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] source ... target

(dev) go|c:\> python -c "import os;os.system('scp')"
'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

try using absolute path:

```
(dev) go|c:\> whereis scp
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe

(dev) go|c:\> python -c "import os;os.system(r'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe')"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Python can't even list the directory:

```
(dev) go|c:\> python -c "import os;len(os.listdir(r'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH'))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\*.*'
```

although it is there:

```
(dev) go|c:\> cd /d c:\windows\system32\openssh
```

and contains `scp.exe`:

```
(dev) go|c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 4C4D-147C

 Directory of c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH

02/12/2019  03:15 AM    <DIR>          .
02/12/2019  03:15 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/15/2018  11:09 AM           322,560 scp.exe
02/12/2019  03:12 AM           322,048 sftp-server.exe
09/15/2018  11:09 AM           390,144 sftp.exe
09/15/2018  11:09 AM           491,520 ssh-add.exe
09/15/2018  11:09 AM           384,512 ssh-agent.exe
09/15/2018  11:09 AM           637,952 ssh-keygen.exe
09/15/2018  11:09 AM           530,432 ssh-keyscan.exe
02/12/2019  03:12 AM           149,504 ssh-shellhost.exe
09/15/2018  11:09 AM           882,688 ssh.exe
02/12/2019  03:14 AM           974,848 sshd.exe
02/12/2019  03:12 AM             2,253 sshd_config_default
              11 File(s)      5,088,461 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  812,082,962,432 bytes free
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES` permission on the folder:

```
(dev) go|c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> cd ..

(dev) go|c:\Windows\System32> icacls OpenSSH
OpenSSH NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
        NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(IO)(F)
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(M)
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(M)
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
        BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
        BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
        CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
        APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
        APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
        APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
        APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

but I don't know what to do to give Python the right permissions here...?

Comment: You're probably using 32-bit Python in 64-bit Windows. WOW64 redirects accessing `"%SystemRoot%\System32"` to `"%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64"`. Most executables are distributed as 32-bit builds, but some programs are only 64-bit. This includes the entire OpenSSH directory. In Windows 7+, WOW64 makes the native System32 directory available as `"%SystemRoot%\SysNative"`. It's not a real directory, so it only works in 32-bit programs running in 64-bit Windows. Or just install 64-bit Python.

Comment: Regarding the security on the OpenSSH directory, an access check for a desktop app is based on the enabled groups in the caller's access token. The system evaluates each entry in the access control list until all required access is granted, or some required access is denied. Canonically, deny entries are listed first, but in this case none are present anyway. These are all allow entries. We can see that standard users (i.e. callers with the "BUILTIN\Users" group enabled) are granted read access to the directory, so you have the right to list it. If you didn't, you'd get a `PermissionError`.

Comment: @eryksun I would never even have though about a 32/64 issue. Using a 64-bit Python solved the problem. If you create an answer I'll give you points.. :-)

Comment: Using a 64 bit version of python worked for me as well. Thanks!